# Keyup event getting dead using live of jquery in signal R call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am making sample chat application using signal R but my keyup event is getting dead.I have used clone
This is my sample code

```
//keypress event of textbbox here..
            $(".ChatText").live('keyup', function () {
                if($(".ChatText").val().length > 0)
                {
                alert('test');
                   var messsage_typing=$("#hdnUserName").val() + " is typing...";
                   var strGroupName = $(this).parent().attr('groupname');
                    if (typeof strGroupName !== 'undefined' && strGroupName !== false)
                        chat.server.send($("#hdnUserName").val() + ' : ' + messsage_typing, $(this).parent().attr('groupname'),"1");

                }
            });
            //end of keypress
```

and this is the code of my add message in which i have

```
 chat.client.addMessage = function (message, groupName,recievername,imagetag,Istypingmessage) {

            if ($('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').length == 0) {
                var chatWindow = $("#divChatWindow").clone(true);
                //also tried this not working 
                //var chatWindow = $("#divChatWindow").clone(true,true);
                $(chatWindow).css('display', 'block');
                $(chatWindow).attr('groupname', groupName);

                $("#chatContainer").append(chatWindow);
                //buggy code do not delete..
                //remove all previous li
                $('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul li').remove();
                //replace header tag with new name
                $('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('a').html(recievername);

                $("#chatContainer").draggable();
                $("#chatContainer").css('cursor','move');
            }
```

Please help me out to bind my keyup events here..
Thanks

Comment: `live()` has been removed in the newest version of jQuery ?

Comment: so what to do please help me out

Comment: I am using jquery-1.6.4.js

Comment: yes but that event is not getting triggered after clone I guess..at least in my case it is not working..god knows what is the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning a deep copy of the element

```
var clone = $('.hello').clone(true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents